# git: Make the work tree reflect only a subpath of the whole tree

Tags: git

I would like to checkout a whole branch, but work only inside a specific directory of that branch. Therefore I would like to sort of "dive in" the whole tree and make my work tree reflect only the subdirectory that I chose. E.g.:

```
"master" tree
  dir1/
    file1
    file2
  dir2/
    file3

work-dir tree
  .git
  file1
  file2
```

My guess would be to do it like this:

```
git checkout master:dir1/
```

However, that doesn't work and reports the error:

```
fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'master:dir1/'
```

Is this possible?

Note: I don't want to use submodules because I don't want to slice my repo into unrelated pieces. Subtree merge, as far as I can tell, only helps me to synchronize two separate directories with similar structures but different histories. I want to modify the original objects in the repo and be able to merge them back and forth and retain all the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can however use `cd dir1` and git will still work from there, allowing you to use `git add file1` instead of `git add dir1/file1` etc.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but I really needed to have the subpath contents at the root of my work directory. I accept that git can't do it and will try to work around it some other way.Thanks.